# how can I save editText visibility state (View.GONE)?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, visibility, onsaveinstancestate

I have a problem with editText visibility. In the beginning of my code I've set visibility to GONE

```
editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This part is fine, it sets my editText to GONE. However if i minimise my app and then summon it again, editText field becomes Visible. I've tried to save View setting with SharedPreferences, but i don't know how to do it right.
I am trying to save View with:

```
myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("save steps", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
editor.putInt("visibility", editText.getVisibility());
editor.commit();
```

And then load data back with:

```
editText.setVisibility(myPrefs.getInt("visibility", 0));
```

But this approach crashes my app. Maybe there are any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: maybe this editor.putInt("visibility", editText.getVisibility()); is who are crash the app ,why you dont save true o false and then with if change visibility of editteext?something like if(valor==true)visibility = visible else visibility = gone.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple. When app come back from background, activity restarts (recreate your `edittext`).

You can use `savedInstanceState` or put

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    edittext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

EDIT:
Change:

```
editText.setVisibility(myPrefs.getInt("visibility", 0));
```

to

```
editText.setVisibility(myPrefs.getInt("visibility", View.GONE));
```

I can't see the entire code, maybe app crash is caused by null pointer exception..